# PHP Parse Error: on line 13

Tags: database, authentication, wampserver

Hi guys I am new on PHP and have this problem:

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'yes' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\init.php on line 13
```

This is my code:

```
<?php   

$host = "localhost";
$db_user = "****";
$db_password = "****";
$db_name = "user_db;

mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

if($con)
{

    echo "Connection Success";

}

else
{

    echo "Connection failed";

}

?>
```

**This tutorial I am trying to follow:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxVPGnP_PFM

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: You did not close the quotes at line 6 . But there is no "yes" in this file, so I suspect that the error is in a different file. Also, you do not define $con - it is probably `$con = mysqli_connect(...`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0):

`$con` is missing on line no 8. Where else you are checking it on line no 10 but can not do that until you declare it before the `if`-statement.
Replace line no 8 to this.

```
$db_name = "user_db";
//                 ^   missing closing quote

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);
```

Comment: Still, as stated by @LSerni the closing quotes on line 6 are missing.

Comment: If this answered your question you might consider accepting it. For more information please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and  the rest of the help. It is probably a good idea to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).